# user defined data types allowed in testing views?

Tags: tsqlt

I'm using tsqlt to test a view -- OrderHeader, which joins OrderHeader with OrderState.  In a set up procedure I create fake tables for those two tables, and insert rows.  The table defs and user defined data types are below.

When I run the tsqt procedure I've written to test the views, I create an expected table

```
CREATE TABLE expected_v_ctOrderHeader
        (
        [countOrderNumber] dbo.orderNumber NOT NULL
        ,[orderId] dbo.id NOT NULL
        ,[orderType] dbo.orderType NOT NULL
        ,[orderClass] dbo.orderClass NOT NULL
        ,[orderState] dbo.orderState NOT NULL
        ,[site] dbo.site NOT NULL
        ,[region] [dbo].[region] NULL
        ,[currentInstance] INT NOT NULL
        ,[prOrderId] [dbo].[id] NULL 
        ,[description] dbo.description NULL
        ,[isSoftCount] BIT NOT NULL
        ,[dtDue] DATETIMEOFFSET NULL
        ,[orderMethod]  [dbo].[orderMethod] NOT NULL
        ,[availableForCounting] BIT NOT NULL
        );

Insert into it the same data as in the SetUp procedure:

    INSERT INTO dbo.expected_v_ctOrderHeader
        (
         [countOrderNumber]
        ,[orderId]
        ,[orderType]
        ,[orderClass]
        ,[orderState]
        ,[site]
        ,[region]
        ,[currentInstance]
        ,[prOrderId]
        ,[description]
        ,[isSoftCount]
        ,[dtDue]
        ,[orderMethod]
        ,[availableForCounting]
        )
    VALUES
           ('10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'10'
           ,'1'
           ,'1/1/2020'
           ,'10'
           ,'1')
          ,('100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'100'
           ,'1'
           ,'2/1/2020'
           ,'100'
           ,'0')
          ,('200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'200'
           ,'0'
           ,'3/1/2020'
           ,'200'
           ,'1')

Do an EXEC tsqlt.AssertEqualsTable


    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable
        @Expected = N'dbo.expected_v_ctOrderHeader' 
      , @Actual = N'dbo.v_ctOrderHeader'
```

The base tables are defined using user defined types as follows:

The UDTs are as follows:

```
[dbo].[orderNumber] VARCHAR(50)
[dbo].[id]          INT
[dbo].[orderType]   NVARCHAR(50)
[dbo].[orderClass]  NVARCHAR(50)
[dbo].[orderState]  NVARCHAR(50)
[dbo].[site]        VARCHAR(50)
[dbo].[region]      VARCHAR(50)
[dbo].[description] NVARCHAR(500)
[dbo].[orderMethod] NVARCHAR(50)
```

The view definition is:

```
SELECT ch.[countOrderNumber]    --[dbo].[orderNumber]
      ,ch.[orderId]             --[dbo].[id] 
      ,ch.[orderType]           --[dbo].[orderType]
      ,ch.[orderClass]          --[dbo].[orderClass]
      ,ch.[orderState]          --[dbo].[orderState]
      ,ch.[site]                --[dbo].[site] 
      ,ch.[region]              --[dbo].[region]
      ,ch.[instance] AS currentInstance  --INT
      ,ch.[prOrderId]           --[dbo].[id] 
      ,ch.[description]         --[dbo].[description]
      ,ch.[isSoftCount]         --BIT
      ,ch.[dtDue]               --DATETIMEOFFSET
      ,ch.[orderMethod]         --[dbo].[orderMethod]
      ,cs.[availableForCounting]--BIT
  FROM [dbo].[ctOrderHeader] ch
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[ctOrderState] cs ON ch.orderState = cs.orderState
```

--tsql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctOrderHeader](
    [countOrderNumber] [dbo].[orderNumber] NOT NULL,
    [orderId] [dbo].[id] NOT NULL,
    [orderType] [dbo].[orderType] NOT NULL,
    [orderClass] [dbo].[orderClass] NOT NULL,
    [orderState] [dbo].[orderState] NOT NULL,
    [site] [dbo].[site] NOT NULL,
    [region] [dbo].[region] NULL,
    [instance] [int] NOT NULL,
    [prOrderId] [dbo].[id] NULL,
    [description] [dbo].[description] NULL,
    [isSoftCount] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [dtDue] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [orderMethod] [dbo].[orderMethod] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ctOrderHeader_countOrderNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [countOrderNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_ctOrderHeader_countOrderNumber] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [countOrderNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctOrderState](
    [orderState] [dbo].[orderState] NOT NULL,
    [description] [dbo].[description] NOT NULL,
    [displayName] [dbo].[displayName] NOT NULL,
    [availableForCounting] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ctOrderState_orderState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [orderState] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

--

The tsql test fails (it should pass), with the following message:
(1 row affected)
[v_ctOrderHeader].[Test Data] failed: (Failure) Unexpected/missing column(s)

One example 'missing' column is
|< countOrderNumber, with a system_type_id AND user_type_id as VARCHAR(50)
The actual countOrderNumber is system_type_id = VARCHAR(50) and user_type_id = dbo.orderNumber.

I have tried all permutations for creating the expected table (using the UDT, or not) and always get the same error.
I have also tried inserting into a temp table the results of the view:

SELECT * INTO #t FROM v_ctOrderHeader

```
EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable
    @Expected = N'dbo.expected_v_ctOrderHeader' -- nvarchar(max)
  , @Actual = #t
```

And get the identical errors (mismatches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating ***both*** the actual and expected tables via **SELECT .. INTO**?

This will create both tables with exactly the same format and remove the column difference. Use **TOP(0)** for the expected table. An example test is:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC v_ctOrderHeader.[Test Data]
AS

--arrange
SELECT TOP (0)
       *
INTO v_ctOrderHeader.Expected
FROM dbo.YourViewName;

--populate v_ctOrderHeader.Expected

EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'dbo.ctOrderHeader';
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'dbo.ctOrderState';

--populate dbo.ctOrderHeader
--populate dbo.ctOrderState

--act
SELECT *
INTO v_ctOrderHeader.Actual
FROM dbo.YourViewName;

--assert
EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable @Expected = N'v_ctOrderHeader.Expected', -- nvarchar(max)
                             @Actual = N'v_ctOrderHeader.Actual',     -- nvarchar(max)
                             @Message = N'',                          -- nvarchar(max)
                             @FailMsg = N'';                          -- nvarchar(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate the problems you are seeing and am able to run th test you have provided without error, i.e. it passes as expected.

For reference, I am running SQL2017 and tSQLt 1.0.5873.27393.

This is my code (all in one block for ease):

```
--!
--! Create base objects
--!
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[orderNumber] FROM varchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[id]          FROM int ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[orderType]   FROM nvarchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[orderClass]  FROM nvarchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[orderState]  FROM nvarchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[site]        FROM varchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[region]      FROM varchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[description] FROM nvarchar(500) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[orderMethod] FROM nvarchar(50) ;
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[displayName] FROM nvarchar(128) ;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctOrderState](
    [orderState] [dbo].[orderState] NOT NULL,
    [description] [dbo].[description] NOT NULL,
    [displayName] [dbo].[displayName] NOT NULL,
    [availableForCounting] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ctOrderState_orderState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [orderState] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ctOrderHeader](
    [countOrderNumber] [dbo].[orderNumber] NOT NULL,
    [orderId] [dbo].[id] NOT NULL,
    [orderType] [dbo].[orderType] NOT NULL,
    [orderClass] [dbo].[orderClass] NOT NULL,
    [orderState] [dbo].[orderState] NOT NULL,
    [site] [dbo].[site] NOT NULL,
    [region] [dbo].[region] NULL,
    [instance] [int] NOT NULL,
    [prOrderId] [dbo].[id] NULL,
    [description] [dbo].[description] NULL,
    [isSoftCount] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [dtDue] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [orderMethod] [dbo].[orderMethod] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ctOrderHeader_countOrderNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [countOrderNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_ctOrderHeader_countOrderNumber] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [countOrderNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

IF OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[v_ctOrderHeader]'), N'IsView') = 1
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[v_ctOrderHeader]
GO
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[v_ctOrderHeader]
AS
    SELECT ch.[countOrderNumber]    --[dbo].[orderNumber]
          ,ch.[orderId]             --[dbo].[id] 
          ,ch.[orderType]           --[dbo].[orderType]
          ,ch.[orderClass]          --[dbo].[orderClass]
          ,ch.[orderState]          --[dbo].[orderState]
          ,ch.[site]                --[dbo].[site] 
          ,ch.[region]              --[dbo].[region]
          ,ch.[instance] AS currentInstance  --INT
          ,ch.[prOrderId]           --[dbo].[id] 
          ,ch.[description]         --[dbo].[description]
          ,ch.[isSoftCount]         --BIT
          ,ch.[dtDue]               --DATETIMEOFFSET
          ,ch.[orderMethod]         --[dbo].[orderMethod]
          ,cs.[availableForCounting]--BIT
      FROM [dbo].[ctOrderHeader] ch
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[ctOrderState] cs ON ch.orderState = cs.orderState
GO

--!
--! Create test objects
--!
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'StackOverflowTests';
GO

IF OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID(N'[StackOverflowTests].[SetUp]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [StackOverflowTests].[SetUp]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [StackOverflowTests].[SetUp]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'dbo.ctOrderState' ;
    EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'dbo.ctOrderHeader' ;

    INSERT dbo.ctOrderState (orderState, [description] , displayName, availableForCounting)
    VALUES (10, 'Not Specified 10', 'Number 10', 1 )
        ,  (100, 'Not Specified 100', 'Number 100', 1 )
        ,  (200, 'Not Specified 200', 'Number 200', 1 )
    ;

    INSERT dbo.ctOrderHeader
    (
      countOrderNumber
    , orderId
    , orderType
    , orderClass
    , orderState
    , site
    , region
    , instance
    , prOrderId
    , description
    , isSoftCount
    , dtDue
    , orderMethod
    )
    VALUES
    (
      '10'                 -- countOrderNumber - orderNumber
    , 10                   -- orderId - id
    , '10'                 -- orderType - orderType
    , '10'                 -- orderClass - orderClass
    , '10'                 -- orderState - orderState
    , '10'                 -- site - site
    , '10'                 -- region - region
    , 10                   -- instance - int
    , 10                   -- prOrderId - id
    , '10'                 -- description - description
    , 1                -- isSoftCount - bit
    , '20200101' -- dtDue - datetimeoffset(7)
    , '10'                 -- orderMethod - orderMethod
    )
    , (
      '100'                -- countOrderNumber - orderNumber
    , 100                  -- orderId - id
    , '100'                -- orderType - orderType
    , '100'                -- orderClass - orderClass
    , '100'                -- orderState - orderState
    , '100'                -- site - site
    , '100'                -- region - region
    , 100                  -- instance - int
    , 100                  -- prOrderId - id
    , '100'                -- description - description
    , 1                -- isSoftCount - bit
    , '20200102' -- dtDue - datetimeoffset(7)
    , '100'                -- orderMethod - orderMethod
    )
    , (
      '200'                -- countOrderNumber - orderNumber
    , 200                  -- orderId - id
    , '200'                -- orderType - orderType
    , '200'                -- orderClass - orderClass
    , '200'                -- orderState - orderState
    , '200'                -- site - site
    , '200'                -- region - region
    , 200                  -- instance - int
    , 200                  -- prOrderId - id
    , '200'                -- description - description
    , 0                -- isSoftCount - bit
    , '20200103' -- dtDue - datetimeoffset(7)
    , '200'                -- orderMethod - orderMethod
    )
    ;

END
GO

IF OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID(N'[StackOverflowTests].[test v_ctOrderHeader join conditione]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [StackOverflowTests].[test v_ctOrderHeader join condition]
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [StackOverflowTests].[test v_ctOrderHeader join condition]
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE expected_v_ctOrderHeader
            (
            [countOrderNumber] dbo.orderNumber NOT NULL
            ,[orderId] dbo.id NOT NULL
            ,[orderType] dbo.orderType NOT NULL
            ,[orderClass] dbo.orderClass NOT NULL
            ,[orderState] dbo.orderState NOT NULL
            ,[site] dbo.site NOT NULL
            ,[region] [dbo].[region] NULL
            ,[currentInstance] INT NOT NULL
            ,[prOrderId] [dbo].[id] NULL 
            ,[description] dbo.description NULL
            ,[isSoftCount] BIT NOT NULL
            ,[dtDue] DATETIMEOFFSET NULL
            ,[orderMethod]  [dbo].[orderMethod] NOT NULL
            ,[availableForCounting] BIT NOT NULL
            );

        -- INSERT into it the same data as in the SetUp procedure:
        INSERT INTO dbo.expected_v_ctOrderHeader
            (
             [countOrderNumber]
            ,[orderId]
            ,[orderType]
            ,[orderClass]
            ,[orderState]
            ,[site]
            ,[region]
            ,[currentInstance]
            ,[prOrderId]
            ,[description]
            ,[isSoftCount]
            ,[dtDue]
            ,[orderMethod]
            ,[availableForCounting]
            )
        VALUES
               ('10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'10'
               ,'1'
               ,'20200101'
               ,'10'
               ,'1')
              ,('100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'100'
               ,'1'
               ,'20200102'
               ,'100'
               ,'1')
              ,('200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'200'
               ,'0'
               ,'20200103'
               ,'200'
               ,'1');

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable
        @Expected = N'dbo.expected_v_ctOrderHeader' 
      , @Actual = N'dbo.v_ctOrderHeader' 
END
GO

--!
--! Run the tests
--!
EXEC tSQLt.Run 'StackOverflowTests';
GO
```

And this is the result I get:

```
+----------------------+
|Test Execution Summary|
+----------------------+

|No|Test Case Name                                            |Dur(ms)|Result |
+--+----------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+
|1 |[StackOverflowTests].[test v_ctOrderHeader join condition]|     47|Success|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case Summary: 1 test case(s) executed, 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 errored.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Are you doing anything different in your test or setup than I am doing above?  Maybe an older version of tSQLt?

Hope this helps

Comment: I checked my version and it is the same.  The original test I was working on was going to test schemas (check whether the view or underlying table ddl ever changes) then the data (does the view still return correct data).  I figured out eventually that you can't test schemas for views (only tables).  

When building the script I kept getting mismatches between the types in the view and the expected table, although your test does succeed.  I had a few eyes on this and we couldn't find what was wrong, but got around it by selecting both actual and expected into temp tables and comparing those.